# Test Sitecore personalization on Non-Prod enviroment

Tags: personalization

We want to test Sitecore personalization on staging instance before directly making changes on live pages.
We have one Geo IP location license active on prod CM instance, so to test personalization implementation on staging instance **Do we need one more license?**

I think country related condition that we apply in Rule Set editor is associated with Geo IP location application so personalization will work only on prod not in non-prod env.

Answer (score 5):

If all you want to do is test country and IP on your content before it goes live, you can use the Experience Explorer. It lets you specify an IP or Country and see what your personalization will look like.

[image]

In the left panel you can specify your personalization details. Just a reminder you have to click the little arrow again the left side to pull the experience explorer panel out.

[image]

Comment: Ok that means based on these parameters ( IP / Country ) we will be able to see changing layout/rendering of page as per defined personalization settings even on Prod CM instance in Preview mode. Am I Correct?

and do we really need Geo IP location license to run personalization on our website

Comment: one more thing that Explore link is disable for me

Comment: You are correct, you can see exactly what it will look like based on IP, Country, time, persona, etc....

Comment: So we need to solve the Explorer link unavailable. It sounds like maybe staging is missing the XP license? Is the staging license key the same as production?

Comment: To validate if XP license is same in both env. I think  I have to check that key in license.xml file If so what should I search in this xml file

Actually on Prod CM instance also Explore link is not available for me whereas I can see visitors tracking data in Experience Analytics dashboard

Answer (score 0):

If your company is Sitecore Partner, you can also request partner benefits such as device detection, EXM cloud delivery service and Geo location. Please connect with your regional Sitecore office and request the license.